# Skip first line execution from while loop

Tags: selenium

I created a code in while loop in Orange HRM. 
I am taking data for UID & Pwd from a text file.
But while Executing that it executes 1st line also, which is not necessary.
I want to skip the first line (UID, PWD) and proceed further.
I want the Solution with While as well as with For Loop.

I think It's simple but i am unable to do it immediately.
Please find my code written with while loop.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:/WorkSpace/Test/InputData/uid.txt"));
String sCurrentLine;

while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine())!= null)
{
    String str[] = sCurrentLine.split(" ");     
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername")).sendKeys(str[0]);
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys(str[1]);
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    if (driver.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getAttribute("id").contains("welcome")) 
    {
        System.out.println("Login is Successful");
        temp = true;
        break;
    } 
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Login Failed");
        temp = false;
        driver.navigate().to("http://opensource.demo.orangehrm.com/");
    }
    if (temp) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip the first line, read it before the loop:

```
br.readLine()
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine())!= null)
{
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just move the code you want executed only once, outside of the loop?  Put it right before the loop, and it'll be executed, then go immediately into the loop.

Or you could have something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
         //code you want executed
    }
}
```